# Azure SQL wait operation timed out

Tags: performance, azure-sql-database

I'm about ready to abandon Azure SQL for reliability issues, but I thought I'd check here first. I'm getting several sporadic timeout errors on SQL Azure. This is not a connection string issue - we're talking about several different apps that have been running for quite some time without issue. The exact error is:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out
```

At present time, I'm looking at 300 of these over the past 30 minutes or so. I ran the DMV query mentioned at http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/05/14/sql-server-find-most-expensive-queries-using-dmv to find out what's going on, and found this:

[image]

According to the documentation, 602,382 is microseconds, or roughly 602 milliseconds, so obviously my database usage requirements are pretty damn low. I have a feeling this is purely an over-tenancy issue on the part of Azure SQL. Is there any other possible explanation? Any potential resolution short of leaving Azure SQL for greener pastures (e.g. dedicated SQL VM)?

Comment: Hi sorry I know this is old stuff but this is the only post that really relates to what I'm experiencing.I''m running into similar issues and I've noticed that it's more likely to happen when the web app has gone idle or inactive for a while. Did you notice anything similar ? which solution did you end up using ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes,  you're right, you're probably being stifled by other high-resource utilizing tenants that have been placed on the same machine your db was on.

By default, Sql Azure provides guarantees an SLA on availability but not performance. If you're looking for consistency in performance, you should look into their premium tier: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/sql-database/

In the premium tier, your db will be guaranteed say a couple of cores, memory and IOPS (think of it like a mini VM)

Answer (score 1):

This error may occur due to a slow internet connection on the target machine.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the premium reservations in SQL Azure, it is more expensive but you get isolated from "tenant neighbor noise".  It is in preview mode and it has some important improvements: removes max connection limit, no max log limit, no throttling and no neighbor noise.

dedicated VMs for SQL Server suck right now because of complex set up required for networking to work with cloud serviced and for high availability.  Also simple things like backups require additional jobs unless you are running SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 0):

With a cloud DB you probably should implement a retry mechanism and then an way to track how often it fails - and ideally tell the end user there is a temporary problem